# ¿Como seleccionar un option de un select (con valores cargados desde mariadb) que se encuentra en una modal abierta con eventClick de fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, ajax, mariadb, fullcalendar, html-select

los pongo en situación estoy realizando una aplicación web en la cual implemente fullcalendar para poder crear una agenda, en la cual al darle click a algun dia te muestre una ventana modal en el cual haya un formulario para registrar el evento, pero yo necesitaba utilizar un select para cargar los tipos de vehiculos lo cual logre con este codigo:

```
getvehiculoss();
function getvehiculoss(){
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "(aqui pongo la ruta de mi consulta)", 
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key, registro) {
      $("#SelectVehiculo").append('<option value='+registro.id_vehiculo+' data-icon="../../web/img/vehiculos/'+registro.foto+'">'+registro.placa+'</option>');

    });        
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert('error al traer los vehiculos');
  }
});
}
```

y me funciona me carga el select y tambien me hace el insert correctamente tomando el valor del select, mi problema es ya al mostrar el dato seleccionado para poder editar(utilizo la misma modal para poder editar y agregar), bien pues mi idea era esa al darle click al evento que se me cargase su informacion en los campos de la modal y que me diese la opción de modificar y cargo correctamente todos los datos en funcion "eventClick" que tiene full calendar cargo los datos tipo asi:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    //Abre la modal de ejemplo
    $('#modalprueba').modal();        
    $('#modalprueba').modal('open');   
    */        
    //tomo los valores y los cargo
    $('#txtID').val(calEvent.id_agenda_clase);
    $('#txtTitulo').val(calEvent.title);
    //aqui intento hacer que seleccione el valor en mi select
    $('#SelectVehiculo').val(calEvent.id_vehiculo);
  }
```

(donde "SelectVehiculo" es el id de mi select y "calEvent.id_vehiculo", es lo que obtengo de mi base de datos), en teoría debería de funcionar, pero no lo hace, y intente poner eso mismo pero afuera de

```
$('#calendarioWeb').fullCalendar({"codigo del calendario"})
```

y si se cambia por ejemplo le pongo

```
$('#SelectVehiculo').val(3);
```

me lo carga exactamente como debería, ya estuve mucho tiempo leyendo y buscando información de como hacerlo y no encuentro nada que me funcione, si me ayudaran estaría muy agradecido, gracias﻿